# Initializing SwiftUI view with <Spacer>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I see code like this in SwiftUI view body to initialise and put a view:

```
 MyView<Spacer>("xyz",
                    image: "myimage",
                    color: .orange,
                    binding: self.$demoBinding
                )
```

I want to know what does the use of generic`<Spacer>` do here, what do the syntax rules say?

Here is the declaration and initializer of `MyView`:

```
typealias Action = () -> Void

struct MyView<Content: View>: View {

  private var text, hint: String
  private var image: String?
  private var color: Color?

  private var content: Content?
  private var onClick: Action?

  private var useToggle: Bool
  @Binding private var toggleState: Bool

  init(_ text: String, hint: String = "", image: String? = nil, color: Color? = nil, binding: Binding<Bool>) {
    
 }
```

}

Comment: Well syntactically, `Spacer` is the type argument for `MyView`, the same way that in `Array<Int>`, `Int` is the type argument for `Array`. I can't say anything else about what the code does without seeing what `MyView` is.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the code.

Comment: Can you show the whole declaration of `MyView`?

Comment: @Sweeper Sure, please see edits.

Comment: You *still* haven't show the whole declaration.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, what is `MyView` supposed to look like? `MyView` is not its actually name, is it? What is it actually called?

Comment: Ok, I shall try to put the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyView<Spacer>()`

Likely starts something like

```
struct MyView<Something>: View where Something == AnyType {


}
```

Then it uses `Something` in the properties.

```
struct MyView<Something>: View where Something == AnyType {
     let something: Something

}
```

The most common use for SwiftUI is passing around "Content"

```
struct MyView<Something>: View where Something : View {
     @ViewBuilder var someView: Something

     var body: some View {
         someView
     }

}
```

I suggest looking at the Swift Protocols section so you can learn a bit more on the subject

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols/